# Have cursor on editable Combobox inside DataGridTemplateColumn on pressing F2

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `DataGrid` and an editable `DataGridComboBoxColumn` column inside it.

I wish to horizontally center the content of this combobox column. I tried many things and found many solutions, none of which worked for me. Then I came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548646/4062881) solution. (Using a `ComboBox` inside `DataGridTemplateColumn`)

The problem is that in my case the `ComboBox` is editable. So when user presses `F2` key to edit the content of the `ComboBox` cell, the focus won't appear inside the editable `ComboBox`. A mouse click on that cell however works. I am assuming it's obviously because the combobox is inside the template column type. But I want that the cursor appears inside the combobox and it becomes editable when user presses F2 when focused on that cell.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question `Title` and your intended question doesn't match.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks for letting me know! @AnjumSKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `PreparingCellForEdit` event for the `DataGrid`, find the `TextBox` in the visual tree and focus it by calling the `Keyboard.Focus` method:

```
private void dataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = GetChildOfType<TextBox>(e.EditingElement);
    if (textBox != null)
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="test" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="..." />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                                      FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus">
                        <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```